# Is there any way I can abbreviate list of column in the GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql

I have GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Looking for something like GROUP BY 1:10

Comment: I have never seen such a `GROUP BY` abbreviation. However, if you mention the SQL dialect (MySQL, SQL Server, SQLite...) then perhaps sb nows where to find a syntax diagram that will give you the final answer.

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing (which is not necessarily to say that it doesn't exist...), and I really can't imagine a parser just assuming column names/aliases like that.